# Vedic verses connecting Gunas and Varnas

Tags: identification-request, gunas, varna

Are there any verses in the Vedas, **CLEARLY connecting Gunas with Varnas?**

Let me clarify what I am looking for. I am looking for verses that define;

A particular Guna or a combination of particular Gunas makes a Brahmana,

A particular Guna or a combination of particular Gunas makes a Kshatriya,

A particular Guna or a combination of particular Gunas makes a Vaishya,

A particular Guna or a combination of particular Gunas makes a Shoodra.

> ### Edit 2
>
> **To make things more clear:** The Triguna concept is that; everyone and everything has all three (satvarajastamo) gunas, only in DIFFERENT
>   PROPORTIONS and in DIFFERENT CONTEXTS. The living being or substance
>   is viewed as the net result of the joint effect of different
>   proportions of these three qualities. What I seek is: Vedic or
>   Samkhyic verses that describe, that such and such proportions of the
>   Trigunas, make a being, a Brahmana, a Kshyatriya, a Vaishya and a
>   Shoodra.

For example, take the verses from the Bhagavdgeeta, Chapter 14, Verses 14 & 15;

> यदा सत्त्वे प्रवृद्धे तु प्रलयं याति देहभृत्। तदोत्तमविदां
>   लोकानमलान्प्रतिपद्यते।।14.14।।
>
> If Satva is predominating at the time
>   of death in a person, he attains the pure worlds of the highest sages.
>
> रजसि प्रलयं गत्वा कर्मसङ्गिषु जायते। तथा प्रलीनस्तमसि मूढयोनिषु
>   जायते।।14.15।।
>
> With Rajas predominating at the time of death one is
>   born among those attached to actions. In the same manner with the
>   predominance of Tamas, he takes birth among ignorant people.

I am seeking only verses from the Vedas [Or could be even from the Samkhya-Karika. Note that it is accepted that the concept of Gunas originated in the Samkhya philosophy.] but not from the Bhagavadgeeta or any other scripture.

> ### Edit 1
>
> **Why I am only interested in the Vedas and the Samkhya Karika? Why not other scriptures?**
>
> Because I am seeking the thoughts at their origin.
>
> Historically, the origin of the Samkhya philosophy is not clear. It is
>   still debated whether the origin of the Samkhya philosophy was
>   Upanishadic or Non-vedic. But I am not interested in where it
>   originated. I am interested in what the original thought is. In the
>   Bhagavadgeeta, though the Samkhya philosophy blossoms fully &
>   beautifully, it is not the original thought. Geeta repeatedly tells us
>   that the 'Gunas' is the Samkhya thought. Historically too it is
>   accepted that the Trigunas/Gunatrayas is Samkhya concept.
>
> And similarly the 'Varnas' thought first appears in the Vedas. The
>   concept is generally traced back to the Purusha Sukta verse of the Rig
>   Veda.
>
> So I just want to get to study the 'Gunas', 'Varnas' and their
>   'Interlinkings' in their original forms.
>
> And then, I wish to avoid confusion by twisted and biased
>   interpretations of the concepts.

Comment: Why are you only interested in the Vedas and the Samkhya Karika?  Why not other scriptures?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan cos.other scripture maybe contradictory

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan - Thanks for asking the clarification. Sorry, I forgot to distinctly clarify it in the post. [I just hinted by saying "Note that it is accepted that the concept of Gunas originated in the Samkhya philosophy".] Moreover, as Rakesh Joshi rightly put it, I want to avoid confusion created by twisted and biased interpretations of the concepts. I will edit the post. And Nog Shine thanks for trimming the post.

Comment: the development of gunas is later, there are a few references in the vedas to 'colors' - red, white, and black- which developed later into the gunas. This has been covered in other questions already. do a search.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I did search and didn't find. I do not seek to know how the Triguna concept developed or originated. I would like to study it in its original form. And that original form can only be found in the Vedas or the Samkhykarika. May be I should edit the post to make it more clear. I solicit Vedic or Samkhyic verses that describe, what proportions of the Trigunas, make the chaturvarnas.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17113/7853

Comment: @RakeshJoshi. Though some matters are interesting like classification of planets... and good pointers like Manusmriti saying Brahmana becomes a Vaishya by selling milk... there are no citations of authoritative Vedic or Samkhyic Verses that describe, a particular admixture of Trigunas making a particular Varna. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @AnilKagi because it is not a strict.compartment model. You will only in geeta and vedantic texts

Comment: see my answer to this question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16355/bg-14-8-what-is-the-source-of-the-scriptural-definition-of-mode-of-ignorance/16405#16405